# Build a Digital Audio Workstation (DAW)

Tags: windows, open-source, software-development, audio

I plan to build a professional, yet simple to use, DAW for Windows. Mainly, what I found so far, was making contributions to existing DAW projects.

I recently discovered the open source projects: 'Ardour' and 'JUCE'.
Are there any more open source software (or engines) available out there? Which ones are easy to use, and flexible enough to allow changes in the core and UI of the program?

Thanks, Paulo.

Answer (score 1):

[LMMS](https://lmms.io/) is a very nice DAW:

- It's free, open source (GPL) and cross platform
- It has a built-in compressor, limiter, delay, reverb, distortion, EQ, bass-enhancer
- It has LADSPA and VST plugin support
- And a lot more features...

Answer (score 0):

[Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/) could be a good place to start looking:

- Free, Open Source & Cross Platform
- GPL
- Possibly one of the most feature rich audio editing/mixing/recording platforms
- Support for LADSPA, LV2, Nyquist, VST and Audio Unit effect plug-ins
- Custom Audio Unit effect plug-ins in [Nyquist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_(programming_language))
- Experimental plug-in module Mod-script pipe to allow control via named pipes with examples in pearl.
- Batch scripting language
- Actively developed